# Настройка SQL запросов в Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Добрый день, разрабатываю систему отчетности в виде web-приложения. Использую Spring и Hibernate.

Сделал xml файл ИмяСущности.hbm.xml, в него положил запрос CDATA.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="domain.Worklog" table="worklog">
<id name="id" column="id" />
  <property name="author" column="AUTHOR" type="string"/>
  <property name="startdate" column="STARTDATE" type="date"/>
  <property name="timeworked" column="timeworked" type="int"/>
</class>

<query name="xmlGetWorkLog">
    <![CDATA[FROM Worklog w WHERE w.author = :user]]>
</query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Хотел бы узнать, есть ли возможность вынести настройки запросов

```
<query name="xmlGetWorkLog">
    <![CDATA[FROM Worklog w WHERE w.author = :user]]>
</query>
```

в отдельный файл общий xml и в файлы сущностей уже его просто импортировать? как-нибудь через mapping resources?

Так как запросы могут меняться, добавлять, удалять, не хотелось бы чтобы это делалось в файле настройки сущностей. А был общий файл настройки запросов и в нем менять.

Толкового не нашел в сети ничего :( Может кто так делал?

Или все же проще делать это через DOM и далее собирать запрос через StringBuilder?

Comment: А если попробовать средствами XML (документация: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-external-ent), как-то так: `<!ENTITY query SYSTEM "query.xml">` и потом в нужном месте вставить `&query;`?

Comment: Что-то не совсем понял как мне это можно сделать :(  Сейчас я сделал отдельный XML, где прописал SQL запросы, и сделал через DOM parser, Ну конечно хотелось бы обойтись без этого, чтобы упростить код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML позволяет включать внешние файлы в основной, так что можно попробовать использовать эту технику следующим образом:

*entity.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping[
  <!--- здесь включаем внешний файл query.xml --->
  <!ENTITY query SYSTEM "query.xml">
]>

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="domain.Worklog" table="worklog">
  <id name="id" column="id" />
    <property name="author" column="AUTHOR" type="string"/>
    <property name="startdate" column="STARTDATE" type="date"/>
    <property name="timeworked" column="timeworked" type="int"/>
  </class>
  &query; <!--- а здесь используем подключенный файл --->
</hibernate-mapping>
```

*query.xml:*

```
<query name="xmlGetWorkLog">
    <![CDATA[FROM Worklog w WHERE w.author = :user]]>
</query>
```

Надеюсь, что это поможет. В принципе большинство парсеров XML должны понимать данную конструкцию.